# Как в Django обратится к второй базе данных?

Tags: django

Что то в голове не как не укладывается, как мне из под Django обратится к  уже существующей(то есть второй или отдельной БД). допустим есть основная БД сайта(которую Django создал автоматически) db.sqlite3.sqlite3? в settings она прописана так:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    },
```

Но я хочу доставать некоторые данные из второй БД, под названием: BDtest.db
Для этого я прописал её в settings:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    },
    'CSDNbd': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'BDtest'),
    }
}
```

А как мне обратится к данным из уже существующей таблицы? Тем более если она не является дефолтной... 
Ведь когда я создаю модель в models.py то сразу и новая таблица создается, тем более что простое обращение подразумевает обращение к дефолтной БД, или я не правильно понимаю?

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы обратиться к определенной базе данных в QuerySet, вы можете использовать метод `using(alias_db)`, например:

```
MyModel.objects.using('CSDNbd').all()
```

Запросы без указания базы данных будут адресованы в базу данных по умолчанию (default).

Для создания таблицы в определённой базе данных, вам нужно явно указывать алиас базы данных при миграции `python manage.py migrate --database=CSDNbd`.

Для полного контроля миграций и работы с БД можете создать роутер БД.

Но тем не менее нужно помнить о некоторых ограничениях использования нескольких БД в проекте.

Answer (score 0):

Также можно построить свои модели на основе уже существующих в базе данных таблиц, это описано в документации Django: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/legacy-databases/

Использовал такую технику в нескольких проектах, работает.